# Jar file for opencv

Tags: opencv, jar

Do anyone have the jar file for opencv version 2.4.4? Any help will be appreciated. I have searched java2s for jar file, but it has only two version 2.4.1 and 2.4.3

Comment: please suggest me some sites to get jar file for it

Comment: Finally i found the jar file for opencv which contains both NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME member as well as VideoCapture class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the jar file for opencv which contains both NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME member as well as VideoCapture class

[This is the link of that jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nu.pattern/opencv/2.4.9-4)